# Why does WPF toggle button pulse once unchecked

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, togglebutton

Within a Desktop app I have a toggle button:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="CFStglBtn" Checked="cfsCBox_Checked"
              Unchecked="cfsCBox_Unchecked"
              IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Image Source="assets\telephone.png" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
        <TextBlock Text="CFS" FontSize="10" Margin="5,5,5,0"
                   Foreground="DarkSlateGray"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ToggleButton>
```

For the Checked event I am setting a value and then executing a method FilterView(); 
//ommitting code

Unchecked state is just the opposite. resets a variable and executed the method again

The question I have is I noticed when I uncheck the toggle button the button continues to pulse or flash ( going from blue to chrome) as if it still has focus. The button will stay like this until another button is clicked.

Is there a way to remove this focus so that when the button is unchecked the button goes back to a unchecked state without the flashing / pulsing color.

- As you can see from above this is a standard toggle button no styles or custom
- I tested this on just a regular button and I found the same occured when clicked the button will continue to pulse / flash until another button is clicked.

How do you work around this or prevent this effect from happening.

Thank you

Comment: not sure why it didn't post but here is the code for the toggle button 
<ToggleButton  x:Name="CFStglBtn" Checked="cfsCBox_Checked"  Unchecked="cfsCBox_Unchecked" IsChecked="True" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="5,0,0,0">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <Image Source="assets\telephone.png" Margin="3,0,0,0" />
                        <TextBlock Text="CFS" FontSize="10" Margin="5,5,5,0" Foreground="DarkSlateGray"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                </ToggleButton>

Comment: Code needs to be preceded by a blank line and indented 4 spaces. Or highlight it and click the "Code Sample" (101010) icon.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is happening because of the button chrome built into the default template for the control. Your only workaround is to re-template the `Button`. [This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee230084.aspx) should get you started.

Comment: Thanks that is perfect I also checked with a peer of mine and he refereced an article from StackOverflow with another solution

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/362993/wpf-template-binding-in-togglebutton-usercontrol

Thanks again!

Answer (score 12):

Set the Button `Focusable="False"`.

Comment: nice easy fix instead of re-templating