# How can I bind a property of a user control to a properties of that same control in WPF?

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Inside my user control I have a collection call Solutions

```
 public List<string> Solutions { get; set; }
```

I want to bind that property to a combobox in xaml of that same user control?

I tried

```
<ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,0,0,41" Name="cbAddSolution" Width="194" Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Solutions}"    />
```

but that didn't seem to work.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Name your UserControl in XAML and refer to it from the binding like so:

```
<UserControl x:Name = "MyUserControl">
  <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,0,0,41" Name="cbAddSolution" Width="194"
            Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding ElementName=MyUserControl, Path=Solutions}" />
</UserControl>
```

If you want proper binding your UserControl should implement INotifyPropertyChanged for that property or make that property a Dependency Property

**Update**

Or use RelativeSource if you don't want to name the UserControl

```
<UserControl>
  <ComboBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="21,0,0,41" Name="cbAddSolution" Width="194"
            Height="21" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Solutions, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}" />
</UserControl>
```

Comment: This work nicely, thank you. I know about the ElementName before. But I thought it can only be used to refer to another element, I didn't know a class in XAML can name itself... that's new to me.

Comment: I wonder is there a away for an object to refer to itself without a name, something like "this" in code...

Comment: Updated the answer with a way to do it without a name

Comment: Thanks for the addition. I've look at RelativeSource too but it wasn't too intuitive. I would thought something like "Self" would make sense. But it seem that what they are doing is walking up the hierarchy starting from self... by using AncestorType.

Answer (score 2):

Move the XAML of your control into the `Template` property, i.e. instead of

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl" ...>
    ...
    <ComboBox ... />
    ...
</UserControl>
```

use

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyUserControl" ...>
    <UserControl.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            ...
            <ComboBox ... />
            ...
        </ControlTemplate>
    </UserControl.Template>
</UserControl>
```

Then, you can use `TemplateBinding`:

```
            <ComboBox ... ItemsSource="{TemplateBinding Solutions}" />
```

BTW, your question is very similar to this one: [Custom UserControl Property used by child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358443/custom-usercontrol-property-used-by-child-element#360700)

Comment: This look interesting, but it require that Solutions have to be static. Is there a way around that?

Comment: Actually, no, `Solutions` doesn't need to be static. (At least it works for me without being static...)

Comment: Hmmm.. I tried and it give me that error when I build the solution. Perhaps I missed something. Will have to try again next time.