# How to make multiple buttons with different backgrounds from one template in Expression Blend 4

Tags: windows-phone-7, expression-blend

I made a simple button template from the rectangle with "Make into control../Button" command. Now, I need several buttons from that template but each button must have different background image. I tried to do that in Blend4 but when I change the button background, button holds to a template background (or none, whichever is set in template), ignoring the image I have set for that specific button. 
Button Template:

```
btnMenu (No brush)
    -rectangle (No brush)
    -[ContentPresenter] (some text)
```

I apreciate any advice.

Style:

```
<Style x:Key="btnStyleMenuHome" TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid x:Name="btnMenu" Width="90" Height="70" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid.Background>
                                <ImageBrush Stretch="None"/>
                            </Grid.Background>
                            <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="MouseOver"/>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                        <Storyboard>
                                            <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Shape.Fill).(TileBrush.Stretch)" Storyboard.TargetName="rectangle">
                                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                        <Stretch>Uniform</Stretch>
                                                    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                                            </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                        </Storyboard>
                                    </VisualState>
                                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                                </VisualStateGroup>
                            </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                            <Rectangle x:Name="rectangle" RadiusY="5" RadiusX="5" StrokeThickness="0" Width="90" Height="70" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <ImageBrush Stretch="None" ImageSource="images/someImage.png"/>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>
                            </Rectangle>
                            <ContentPresenter VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Margin="7,0" d:LayoutOverrides="Width" Height="25" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="Background">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ImageBrush Stretch="None"/>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [Custom UserControl Property used by child element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/358443/custom-usercontrol-property-used-by-child-element)

Comment: Template Style:
btnMenu (No brush)
    -rectangle (No brush)
    -[ContentPresenter] (some text)

As for your second question, I cant find where to set a binding (is it for button or for Style?)